# Should I save a music playlist as binary or text file in java?

Tags: java, netbeans, playlist, audio-player

I'm currently making my own music player in Java (NetBeans IDE), and I'm working out on the playlist, storing the file paths in an array. Should I save those file paths as binary or text? Because I plan on having a "save" and "load" button that would save and load a playlist.

Answer (score 2):

My advice, use the ["cue" sheet format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cue_sheet_%28computing%29) (which is ascii) - from the Wikipedia article, *A cue sheet is a plain text file containing commands with one or more parameters.*

> **Essential commands**
>
> FILE
>
> Names a file containing the data and its format (such as MP3, and WAVE audio file formats, and plain "binary" disc images)
>
> TRACK
>
> Defines a track context, providing its number and type or mode (for instance AUDIO or various CD-ROM modes). Some commands that follow this command apply to the track rather than the entire disc.
>
> INDEX
>
> Indicates an index (position) within the current FILE. The position is specified in mm:ss:ff (minute-second-frame) format. There are 75 such frames per second of audio. In the context of cue sheets, "frames" refer to CD sectors, despite a different, lower-level structure in CDs also being known as frames.[5] INDEX 01 is required and denotes the start of the track, while INDEX 00 is optional and denotes the pregap. The pregap of Track 1 is used for Hidden Track One Audio (HTOA). Optional higher-numbered indexes (02 through 99) are also allowed.
>
> PREGAP and POSTGAP
>
> Indicates the length of a track's pregap or postgap, which is not stored in any data file. The length is specified in the same minute-second-frame format as for INDEX.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you will probably find it more convenient to use `File[]` or `Path[]`.

Prefer text over binary though.

Answer (score 0):

You should always prefer human-readable formats when possible. JSON, XML, or line-oriented text are all good options.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether or not you want the user to be able to open and read the playlist file. Humans can't read binary files, so you should probably use a text file **unless** you want the contents to be unreadable.